# Couchbase with Laravel: Data cannot be inserted in the couchbase

Tags: php, laravel, couchbase

I am new to couchbase and laravel. I am developing an entry form. I am using couchbase as database and in the back-end i am using laravel. when ever i try to insert data in the couchbase, although the query run, but it prints the data on the screen, rather than it stores in the database. Please help me in this issue

This is my model

```
 <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Member extends Model 
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Member extends Model
{
    //

    protected $table = '';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    public static $couchbase_bucket = 'default';
    public static $couchbase_doc = 'doc1';
    protected $fillable = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'father_name',
            'constituency' ,
            'seat_type',
            'profession' ,
            'deprtment' ,
            'cabinet_post',
            'party',
            'date_of_birth',
            'religon' ,
            'marital_status',
            'gender' ,
            'education',
            'present_contact',
            'permanent_contact'
    ];




    public static function create(array $attributes = array()){
       die(print_r($attributes));
        $value = [
           'id' => intval($attributes['id']),
            'name' => $attributes['name'],
            'father_name' => $attributes['father_name'],
            'constituency' => $attributes['constituency'],
            'seat_type' => $attributes['seat_type'],
            'profession' => $attributes['profession'],
            'deprtment' => $attributes['department'],
            'cabinet_post' => $attributes['cabinet_post'],
            'party' => $attributes['party'],
            'date_of_birth' => $attributes['date_of_birth'],
            'religon' => $attributes['religon'],
            'marital_status' => $attributes['marital_status'],
            'gender' => $attributes['gender'],
            'education' => $attributes['education'],
            'present_contact' => $attributes['present_contact'],
            'permanent_contact' => $attributes['permanent_contact'],
        ];
        $key = 'insert:and:delete';
       $result = \DB::connection('couchbase')->table(self::$couchbase_bucket)->key($key)->upsert($value);
       return $result;
    }



    public static function all($columns = array()){
        return \DB::connection('couchbase')->table(self::$couchbase_bucket)->get();

//        DB::connection('couchbase')
//    ->table('testing')->where('whereKey', 'value')->get();
    }




    public static function one($id){
        return \DB::connection('couchbase')->table(self::$couchbase_bucket)->where('id',$id)->get();
    }
}



And the controller is 

    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    use App\Http\Requests;

    use App\Member;

    class memberController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $memberdata = Member::all();

        return view('member.index')->withuserdata($userdata);

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
        return view('member.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //

        $input = $request->all();
        Member::create($input);
        //return redirect('member/index');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in PHP - but I would suggest you to go [here](https://github.com/couchbase/php-couchbase) first and try with the latest sdk, after that - check your connection with a simple php and see if it works.